# Display availability for each option on each attribute

Tags: jquery, object, underscore.js, magento2

I'm trying to set an ID (1 = 'In stock', 2 = 'Some variants in stock' or 3 = 'Made to order') for each option on each attribute so that the user can quickly know which options are in stock before they actually choose them.

**Attributes object:**

```
[
    {
        "id": "93",
        "code": "color",
        "label": "Color",
        "options": [
            {
                "id": "5440",
                "label": "Option 1",
                "products": [
                    "34",
                    "37"
                ],
            },
            {
                "id": "5442",
                "label": "Option 2",
                "products": [
                    "58",
                    "61"
                ],
            },
            {
                "id": "5479",
                "label": "Option 3",
                "products": [
                    "70",
                    "73"
                ],
            },
            {
                "id": "5482",
                "label": "Option 4",
                "products": [
                    "76",
                    "79"
                ],
            },
            {
                "id": "5488",
                "label": "Option 5",
                "products": [
                    "82",
                    "85"
                ],
            },
            {
                "id": "5491",
                "label": "Option 6",
                "products": [
                    "88",
                    "91"
                ],
            },
            {
                "id": "5441",
                "label": "Option 7",
                "products": [
                    "46"
                ],
            }
        ],
        "position": "0"
    },
    {
        "id": "190",
        "code": "color_base",
        "label": "Color Base",
        "options": [
            {
                "id": "5467",
                "label": "Option 1",
                "products": [
                    "34",
                    "46",
                    "58",
                    "70",
                    "76",
                    "82",
                    "88"
                ],
            },
            {
                "id": "5470",
                "label": "Option 2",
                "products": [
                    "37",
                    "61",
                    "73",
                    "79",
                    "85",
                    "91"
                ],
            }
        ],
        "position": "1"
    }
]
```

My initially idea was to grap selected options.id, ie:

```
[
    {
        "id": "5440",
        "label": "Option 1",
        "products": [
            "34",
            "37"
        ],
    },
    {
        "id": "5467",
        "label": "Option 1",
        "products": [
            "34",
            "46",
            "58",
            "70",
            "76",
            "82",
            "88"
        ],
    }

]
```

And from there get available quanties from product by Id in a loop, but I couldn't make it work.

Any ideas on how this can be solved?
It's a Magento project that uses jQuery and underscore.js.

**Edit**

Added some screenshots of the expected result. Sorry for the confusion with "Out of stock", changed to "Made to order". If quantities for product id >= 1, then it should be threated as "In Stock".

Color: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CAzW.png,
Color Base: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Im4cD.png

**Object for quantities**

```
{
    "34": {
        "saleableQty": 12
    },
    "37": {
        "saleableQty": 0
    },
    "46": {
        "saleableQty": 0
    },
    "58": {
        "saleableQty": 1,
    },
    "61": {
        "saleableQty": 1
    },
    "70": {
        "saleableQty": 1
    },
    "73": {
        "saleableQty": 1
    },
    "76": {
        "saleableQty": 1
    },
    "79": {
        "saleableQty": 1
    },
    "82": {
        "saleableQty": 1
    },
    "85": {
        "saleableQty": 1
    },
    "88": {
        "saleableQty": 1
    },
    "91": {
        "saleableQty": 1
    }
}
```

Comment: your question is unclear to me. Can you show what the expected result is and how you determine what is out of stock etc?

Comment: @Kinglish Hi, updated the answer now! Let me know if there is anything that is unclear and I'll try my best to accomondate

Comment: I am looking at your code... where are the quantities shown?

Comment: @Kinglish Updated question now to include the object for quantities

Comment: I *think* your intended algorithm for a given `option` is this: for each `product`, find the `saleableQty`. If all quantities are zero, say "Made to order". If all quantities are greater than zero, say "In stock". Otherwise, say "Some variants in stock". At least that would explain the screenshot. Did I guess right? And if so, what exactly do you expect the output object to look like?